# How to use Apple's SDK constants in a switch while remaining DRY?

Tags: enums, swift

In Apple's `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` class there is a `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreChangeReasonKey` which is the string lookup key for a userInfo notification. Its possible values are

```
var NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreServerChange: Int { get }
var NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreInitialSyncChange: Int { get }
var NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreQuotaViolationChange: Int { get }
var NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreAccountChange: Int { get }
```

I much rather have an enum to benefit from Swift's exhaustive switch checking, and just general style conformity. There has to be an *extremely* obvious reason or design paradigm why putting these constants in an `Enum` is a bad idea or not possible?

Maybe because these values are used inside of a `NSDictionary` and using constants forces the user to downcast NSObjects from the `NSDictionary`, and in general using typed structs/primitives/enums are misleading in this context?

Comment: It was probably converted from Obj-C automatically, with little or no human review.

Comment: That's what I wondering, started thinking whoever wrote this class must know something I don't and made an explicit design choice doing it this way. Or maybe it's just an artifact of legacy? Maybe something about values of a `NSDictionary` can only take `NSObject`s?

Comment: educated guess: In Obj-C it was an anonymous enum, so you can't automatically remove the enum name prefix from the string representations.